# Getting error "No database selected"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Trying to query database table. I'm getting a connection successful result when I run the connection script but can't figure out whats wrong with the query. Sorry I'm new to php

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "laravel";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
    <tr>

    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</table>
<?php endif; ?>

?>
```

Comment: you connected thru PDO but did the rest by using mysql? wut?

Comment: Mixing mysql_ and PDO which obviously will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't MIX them, just use PDO all the way through. Use methods `->query()` and `->fetch()` accordingly.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "laravel";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the PDO error mode to exception

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users');

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
    <tr>

    <?php while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ghost. Sorry I'm new to PHP didn't realise. I'm following a number of tutorials online. All have different syntax. I feel daft now!

Comment: @user2003341 sure im glad this helped, you can check this out to further review its uses http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers